# compare string in multiple object list

Tags: c#

I'm new programming, please excuse me if my question isn't properly ask

so I have an API call that returns

```
public class ProjectMinInfo
 {
        public string ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public class ProjectMinInfos
        {
            [JsonProperty("@odata.context")]
            public string OdataContext { get; set; }
            public List<ProjectMinInfo> value { get; set; }
        }
}
```

I have another Api call that returns multiple result of

```
public class ResourcesAvailable
{
    public string ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ResourceType { get; set; }
    public int ResourceSeq { get; set; }
    public string Companies { get; set; } //note this string could contain more than 1 value i.e "1","5"
    public class ResourcesAvailables
    {
        [JsonProperty("@odata.context")]
        public string OdataContext { get; set; }
        public List<ResourcesAvailable> value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need a function that looks at all the multiple `public string Companies{ get; set; }` in the second API call and then outputs only the result that contains string value similar to `public string Company { get; set; }` in first API call .

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How does the `Companies` property have more then one value?

Comment: What does the value of `Companies` look like. You mention that it could contain more than 1 value. A `string` is a single value (if you discount it being an array of `char`). If a property can contain multiple values it should really be a `List<string>`. Barring that, do the contents have a pattern? For example: "1,2,3,4,5" or "\"1\",\"2\"" or something else?

Comment: hi, the second Api call is for resource group that are connected to multiple companies no i.e company with ID no 1,company with ID no 2, hence why it might return with more than one value in `Companies` such as ` "Companies": "10, 101" `

Comment: So it is a comma separated string?

Comment: yes it is a comma separated string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the string to a list and compare the strings

Lets say you store the results of the first Api call in `ProjectMinInfo projectMinInfo` and the results or the second Api in `List<ResourcesAvailable> resourcesAvailableList` now you need to get the object

```
ResourcesAvailable matchingResource = resourcesAvailableList.Where(x => x.Companies.Split(',').Contains(projectMinInfo.Company)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hello, thank to taking time to help but this will not work for me. so the first APi brings back a project with are the properties of the project, which is the ProjectId, Name and the Company( the which is the company Id) the second API call brings back all the available team with the details above, my idea is to check all the teams Companies connection that matches the Project company id and then display it

Comment: `Company` Is a sting or int?

Comment: What is the content of `Company` and `Companies` look like?

Comment: for the Teams it bring back multiple Json data below  is an example 
 {
            "ResourceSeq": 1873,
            "Description": "Design Engineers",
            "Companies": "10, 101"
        },
{
          "ResourceSeq": 1893,
            "Description": "CAD Machine1",
            "Companies": "50"
        },

Comment: while for the project it brings back 
 {
            "ProjectId": 1893,
            "Description": Build and implementation
            "Company": "50"
        },

Comment: Why are you making it a sting and not an int? How are you deserializing the Json

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProjectMinInfo>(response.Content)` to deserialize the Json

Comment: Does it now answer your question?

Comment: hi thanks for the help, I sorted it by doing this 
 ```foreach (var ResAv in ResourcesAvailables)
            {
                
                
                    if (ResAv.Companies.Split(',').Contains(newAllocationProjectMinInfos.Company))```

Comment: and yes you are correct I stored the result of the first API in newAllocationProjectMinInfos

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not sure I've understood your question properly.

Well, this is what I've understood: You have a `ProjectMinInfo` instance that has a company. Also, you have a collection of `ResourcesAvailable` instances, where each of them has some companies, separated by a comma and a space ", ", like `Company1, Company2, Company3`.

You want to extract that instance of `ResourcesAvailable` that contains the company specified by the `ProjectMinInfo` instance, right?

If so, this is the LINQ Query: Say `project` is an instance of type `ProjectMinInfo`, and resources - a list of `ResourcesAvailable`.

```
// If you want the first resource that matches your condition
var matchingResource = resources
   .FirstOrDefault(q => q.Companies.Split(", ").Contains(project.Company));

// If you want all of the resources that match your condition
var matchingResources = resources
   .Where(q => q.Companies.Split(", ").Contains(project.Company))
   .ToList();
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, feel free to add clarifications ^^

---

Oh, I see the question has been asked in January